# SharePoint Online top navigation/menu not updating - Modern UI

Tags: sharepoint-online, top-navigation, megamenu

What is wrong with the top cascading and megamenu menus in SharePoint?

The changes only show on the computer I am using for editing the menu. It has been days since I made the updates and the client has deleted all cookies etc.

But still hasn't updated.

Any ideas?
Does anyone also have these issues?

Comment: Have you checked the target audience of those Menus ?

Comment: Yes thanks, and thats not the issue

Comment: It seems that either menu that you are adding are only set target audience to you or somehow only draft version is saving instead of published version.

Comment: Thanks Saira but none of that.
I raised a ticket with MS and they couldn't find a solution to it either.
The only thing I have on that side is its using a different language apart from English.

Comment: have you tried using on different computer ? this seems irrelevant but as you have mentioned that only on your computer it works fine. This is bit strange though but trying to find the cause... Also could you share the screenshots.